# ¿como validar columnas de un mismo dataframe - python?

Tags: python

Tengo esta tabla almacenada en un dataframe de pandas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito generar una nueva columna en esta misma tabla (precio_final), en la cual el cual el valor se asigne de acuerdo a la siguiente condición: si el ultimo_precio = 0 entonces asigne precio_referencia, si no asigne ultimo_precio. El resultado debería ser este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo incluir esta condición en mi código de python?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El problema es bastante claro y especifico. No necesita aclaracion sobre que necesita exactamente. Deja de copiar y pegar ese mensaje porque no contribuye a la solucion.

Comment: @LuisFelipe a que te refieres??

Comment: El mensaje firmado por “comunidad” es innecesario, ¿acaso no está claro lo que se pide? Ese usuario para que pierde el tiempo poniendo ese tipo de comentarios que no contribuyen a la solución del problema? Es un reputation w acaso? Fanboy?

Comment: Por favor  añade el código que llevas y coloca tu DataFrame como texto, yo no pienso perdertiempo transcribiendo el DataFrame (y creo que otros usuariostampoco).  Por favor lee [ask] y depaso hacesel [tour]

Comment: @LuisFelipe la pregunta si necesita detalles, pues el autor en ningún momento expone lo que ha intentado ni cual es el problema que tiene con su código. Aquí no se hacen programas, se ayuda con problemas en el código y si el usuario no muestra eso habrá que pedirle que lo haga y si no ha intentando nada hay que pedirle que lo intente. En eso se basa el aprendizaje, no en que otros te hagan las cosas

Comment: @LuisFelipe lo último que diré es que el comentario es muy distinto que la pregunta. Si tu problema es con el comentario entonces debes hacer una pregunta en meta. Pero a la pregunta le falta desarrollo y para ayudar al usuario se le proporciona los enlaces para así mantener la calidad del sitio

Comment: @luisfelipe nosotros al hacer esos comentarios tratamos de que el op reciba la mayor ayuda posible. Hay usuarios que no ayudamos cuando la pregunta no cumple los lineamientos. Además, hay algunos usuarios que no tienen el tiempo de transcribir un dataframe, o no son capaces de ver imagenes en sus dispositivos. Todos quieren ayudar, y para eso a veces el op tiene que dar mas informacion.

Comment: en la practica, esos comentarios no ayudan. ya expuse mi posicion en e otro post, es redundante hacerlo de nuevo

Answer (score -1):

Tu problema es bastante sencillo, el truco esta en que la funcion `.apply` puede ser aplicada a un dataframe de varias columnas, simplemente trata la entrada del `lambda` como una lista a la que accedes a las columnas por indexacion en el orden en que las agregas.

```
>>> df['Precio_final'] = df[['Precio_referencia','Ultimo_precio']].apply(
        lambda x: x[0] if x[1]==0 else x[1], #el if else que indicas
        axis=1) # esto indica que se opera sobre columna
>>> df
       Precio_referencia  Ultimo_precio  Precio_final
0              14000          15000         15000
1              20000              0         20000
2                350            400           400
3                100              0           100
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, ayúdanos a mantener la calidad en el sitio respondiendo a preguntas realizadas en base a [ask], ya que de otra forma contribuyes a que se publiquen preguntas que no son de calidad y que únicamente son de utilidad al OP pero no para la comunidad que es el objetivo del sitio saludos.

Comment: @LuisFelipe completa el [tour] para aprender sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general, y lee [answer]. Lo que Jorgesys está pidiendo es parte de las normas del sitio tal y como se explica en [answer]: "No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real."

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro vótame negativo todo lo que quieras manito, entra a todas las respuestas que he hecho. Tu no eres nadie para decirme que puedo responder o que no. Solo veo que eres otro facista del conocimiento que no quiere compartirlo. Pierdes tu tiempo entrando a las preguntas solo para hacer comentarios que no ayudan al OP.

Comment: @LuisFelipe Como moderador, una de mis tareas es intentar mantener la calidad del sitio evitando publicaciones de bajo nivel. Las respuestas a publicaciones de baja calidad debería evitarse porque tienden a crear problemas y no se ajustan a las normas del sitio (como se indica en [answer]) y te notifiqué sobre el asunto. No es cuestión de no querer compartir conocimiento, lo que se quiere es que ese conocimiento sea de calidad y útil a otros usuarios (cosa que no sucede con publicaciones de baja calidad).